# Assembly file (.s) throwing error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, assembly, xcode6

I have taken over a few projects from a developer and have come across a few issues that I can't resolve. In one project I have an assembly file in the Xcode project labeled as a 'testo.s' file. When I build and run I get an Apple LLVM 6.0 Error with these error specifics below...

testo.s:14:5: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
    MOV r1, r0
    ^

.../testo.s:15:5: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
    mov pc, r0
    ^

.../testo.s:18:5: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
    mov pc, r14
    ^

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

The testo.s assembly file is..

```
.globl _doTesting
.globl _doObserverThing

_doTesting:
  MOV r1, r0
  mov pc, r0
  mov pc, r14
```

Any idea?

Comment: What processor is this for? I'm guessing ARM, but it would be useful to know tht it's not something else.

Comment: Yeah, under my build settings>architectures I have armv7 set. Could it be a compiler issue? I am using the default Apple LLVM 6.0 compiler

Comment: These instructions look fine.  What else are you not showing us?

Comment: I don't know what else to show, I mentioned my compiler and architecture above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

It seems that compiling the project through the Xcode simulator was the culprit since I was able to compile it on a device. I guess the assembly file was written for ARM and the Xcode simulator runs on x86.